# FFXIV window size

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I just tried playing FFXIV on my laptop for the first time today, but currently the window occupies a very small portion of my screen (and strains my eyes for this reason). I can't change it to full screen mode (this option is grayed out) and there doesn't seem to be any clear way to simply change the window size, either.

I am playing on a 13-inch Macbook Pro with a 2880x1600 display (I think these are the dimensions, in any case). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Mac shortcut ^ + ⌘ + F (Control+Cmd+F) to toggle fullscreen? That's a good way to circumvent many application's options menus to get a program to go fullscreen. It won't work for everything, but I suspect it might work for you.